# How to get current number from list of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get number on `mouseover` function

```
<div class="thumb-wrp">
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/2.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/4.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/2.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/4.jpg"></div>
 </div>
```

js

```
$(thumb).mouseover(function(){
    var count = $('.mn-img img').length;
    xx = $(this).length;
    console.log(xx);
});
```

Comment: `I need to get number on mouseover function`, what number?

Comment: If current div is second return 2 :D

Comment: Try `$(this).index();`, it;'ll return the index. This is zero-based index

Comment: you can add data attribute and assign div number value to it. Then you can read it on mouseover.

Comment: How do you define current? In what sense `current number` defines here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are refering to index of div where you are moving your mouse over:

```
$(thumb).mouseover(function(e){
    var imgs = $('.mn-img img');
    var number = imgs.index(e.target);        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
var images = $('.thm-img img'); // get images

// move mouseover onto actual images otherwise you won't know which one is being moused over
images.on('mouseover', function() {
  console.log(images.index($(this)) + 1);  // get index of current image and add 1 (index is 0 based)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-wrp">
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/2.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/4.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/2.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/4.jpg"></div>
 </div>
```

[More information about jQuery index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.thumb-wrp').mouseover(function(){

  var imgs = $('.thm-img img');
    var number = imgs.index(event.target.childNodes[0])+1;
  console.log(number);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-wrp">
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/2.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/4.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/2.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/4.jpg"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a js version:

```js
var all = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.thm-img'));

all.forEach(function (x) {
    x.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {

        console.log(all.indexOf(x)+1)

    })
})
```

```html
<div class="thumb-wrp">
    <div class="thm-img">1
        <img src="img/img/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">2
        <img src="img/img/2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">3
        <img src="img/img/3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">4
        <img src="img/img/4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">5
        <img src="img/img/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">6
        <img src="img/img/2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">7
        <img src="img/img/3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">8
        <img src="img/img/4.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```